# How to make emacs align and indent a bibtex entry?

Tags: latex, indentation, align, bibtex

I want `bibtex-mode` to align and properly indent fields.  I copied a bibtex entry for the following article into Emacs:
[image]
[(Article source here)](http://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&ln=en&p=Measurement+of+colour+flow+with+the+jet+pull+angle+in&of=hx&action_search=Search&sf=earliestdate&so=d&rm=&rg=25&sc=0)

But, with a simple paste, the alignment is lost in Emacs and the indentation is messed up:
[image]

The <kbd>TAB</kbd> key doesn't work to align or indent the entry. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, consider using [`bibslurp`](https://github.com/mkmcc/bibslurp) package, it allows you to retriev BibTeX entries from [The SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System](http://adswww.harvard.edu/) within Emacs itself.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour. What happens if you start Emacs with the `-Q` switch?

Comment: I get the same behaviour when starting with a `-Q` switch

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the cursor is somewhere in the entry, run the command `bibtex-fill-entry` (bound to <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd>), which will
align the fields.  You may also want to set variable `bibtex-align-at-equal-sign` to a non nil value to change the details of alignment.

Comment: Can `bibtex-fill-entry` be applied after each save in bibtex-mode?

Comment: @alper: that's an unrelated question, but you can look at `before-save-hook` and `after-save-hook`.

Comment: I have done it but `bibtex-fill-entry` only work at the block where cursor is at, not on the entire buffer

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, when using the smartparens package in bibtex-mode, where shameful amounts of spaces where inserted. For some reason unknown, bibtex-mode sets the `fill-prefix` variable to a string containing 18 spaces. `(setq fill-prefix nil)` in the `bibtex-mode-hook` fixed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @JonatanLindén, `fill-prefix` is set to a string containing 18 spaces. This is because `bibtex-clean-entry` is using `fill-prefix` to align continuing text after equal sign. Setting `fill-prefix` to `""` can solve the indentation issue. But to have better alignment when formating entry, you can advice `bibtex-clean-entry` to temporarily set `fill-prefix`.

```
(defun bibtex-mode-setup ()
  (setq-local fill-prefix ""))
(add-hook 'bibtex-mode-hook #'bibtex-mode-setup)

(defun bibtex-reset-fill-prefix (orig-func &rest args)
  (let ((fill-prefix (make-string (1+ bibtex-text-indentation) ? )))
    (apply orig-func args)))
(advice-add 'bibtex-clean-entry :around #'bibtex-reset-fill-prefix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would use the `align-regexp` command (or the `align` command if `bibtex-mode` supported it). But that won't help you with the broken indentation.