# How can I apply `bibtex-fill-entry` to the whole buffer?

Tags: hooks, bibtex, save

When I run `bibtex-fill-entry` it formats the current entry block where the cursor is at. Note that `bibtex-fill-entry (C-c C-q) Fill current BibTeX entry`. So I have to traverse all the entries to align them one by one which is time consuming.

Instead I want to apply `bibtex-fill-entry` for all fields in the bibtex buffer, after each save `after-save-hook`.
How can I apply `bibtex-fill-entry` to entire buffer (all the entries)?

---

Here cursor is at the beginning of the `title          = {Clique},` line. When I do `M-x bibtex-fill-entry` it only aligns the first entry. I also want to align second entry (considering all entries in the buffer).

```
@electronic{clique,
        title          = {Clique},
  url          = {https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225/},
}

@electronic{geth,
          title        = {Geth},
  url          = {https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth/},
}
```

Related: [How to make emacs align and indent a bibtex entry?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34147/18414)

Comment: You should be able to create a keyboard macro that does `bibtex-fill-entry` and then `bibtex-next-entry` to get to the next one. Then you can repeat the keyboard macro say 1000 times to do all of them. However, in my experiment `M-}` which is bound to `bibtex-next-entry` does not seem to do anything, but you might want to see if it works for you (I didn't try very hard to make it work).

Comment: @NickD That's a smart solution. I get hard time coding and debugging in lisp. But I will try to implemet what you recommended by looking for solution that repeat keyboard macros from beginning of the buffer.

Comment: Found out what was wrong with `M-}` - see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: There is `bibtex-reformat` which will reformat the whole buffer (or the selected region), so there is no need to define a
macro: `M-x bibtex-reformat` will do it all.

[Obsolete answer]
Go to the beginning of the buffer and create a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html) that does `bibtex-fill-entry` (bound to `C-c C-q`) and then `bibtex-next-entry` (bound to `M-}`):

```
C-x ( C-c C-q M-} C-x )
```

That defines an anonymous macro that you can execute once with `C-x e` to try it out.
You should be at the beginning of the third entry at this point, so all you have to do is repeat the invocation of the macro: `C-u 1000 C-x e`. That will repeat it 1000 times; if you have more entries, just do it again (maybe with a larger number).

---

The reason that `M-}` was ineffective in my case, was that `@electronic` was not a known BibTeX entry type. When I changed it to @article, it worked. I presume there is a way to add new entry types to `bibtex`, but I haven't gone down that path.

Comment: Can we define the macro in the config file by default?

Comment: There is no need for a macro - see the edit.

Comment: To make `bibtex-reformat` work , I have to select complete buffer using `mark-whole-buffer` than apply `bibtex-reformat` right? Could this combined in a single keybinding?

Comment: I don't think so: if you don't have a region defined, it defaults to the whole buffer. There is no need for a single keybinding.